# USB debugging on Samsung Galaxy Tab -- How do I prevent it from resetting debug setting?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, usb-debugging, macos

I have a Samsung Galaxy tab that I'm using for development purposes.  For some reason, when I choose 'Enable USB Debugging' in the settings menu, it turns off after a random period and drops whatever USB connection I have.

I'm debugging on a Macbook Pro, and have one coworker who has similar problems.  Other coworkers don't have this issue.

Comment: What Android version?

Comment: 2.2. Non-rooted device. Kernel - 2.6.32.9

Comment: Are you sure it's not the USB connection dropping and causing USB debugging to get disabled? Perhaps USB debugging only make the problem visible?

Comment: Its possible, but the USB debug checkbox actually gets unset. Additionally, on other Android devices, this isn't a problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem. No obvious reason and/or solution

Comment: Hi,
I have the exact same problem.
I'm doing Adobe Air development on my samsung fascinate.
Just like Daniel, my phone automatically drops the usb debugger on my macbook pro.
I'm running android 2.2 

This is a little bit better than when I had Android 2.1.  Than the phone wouldn't even connect via USB.

But I only get 5 minute intervals to compile my code and test before the usb connection drops.

Very annoying.

Any help would be great. 

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I also see this. I doubt it's the USB connection or the rest of the setup because I can develop & debug for hours with a Moto Droid connected to the same system. Galaxy Tab drops out of USB mode spontaneously after about a minute. Only way to get it back is to unplug the cable, re-enable USB debugging, and reconnect.

One way to keep the Galaxy Tab connected is to click the entry with its serial number in the Devices pane in Eclipse whenever it goes grey. That's only a little less annoying than cycling the USB cable and the debug setting on the Tab because if you wait too long, the Tab disconnects and its entry disappears from Devices.

Comment: I don't have a powered USB hub, but I heard from a developer may solve the problem. If anyone has one, and can see if that fixed there issue, perhaps post that as an answer.

Comment: sucks, but this seems to be the only solution with this particular device

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured out how to get it to stop unchecking the box, though the solution is hardly much less a pain.

If you activate the debugging mode, plug in the cable, run your test and then as soon as you're done testing (or if you're not actually debugging, as soon as the app is installed), unplug it, the checkbox will stay checked indefinitely.

You're still replugging the device every re-compile, but at least you don't have to keep going back to the settings menu to re-check the box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the ADB connection time-out value?

You can find it under Eclipse->Preferences->Android->DDMS

Comment: The issue isn't just an Eclipse issue; even "adb devices" fails to see the device after it disconnects. Also, the "bug" icon in the title bar goes away, so the disconnect definitely happened at the device side. I'll try changing this preference anyway, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this same problem with a Galaxy Tab 4 with Eclipse on OSX.

I found that if you select the "use same device to future launches" option, it'll eliminate having to unplug and plug the USB